# Deleting pairs of duplicates between columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns of data that I need to compare and remove the cells that are duplicated in the other column. There may be multiple cells within each column that are duplicated and some cells may be blank, but I only care about deleting cells with a pair in the other column.

For instance, running the procedure for:

```
    Column A | Column B
    0.1      | 3.2
    0.5      | 0.1
    3.2      | 0.1
    1.4      |
```

Needs to result in:

```
    Column A | Column B
    0.5      | 0.1
    1.4      |
```

Is there any way to do this without using an intermediary conditional formatting?

Comment: Interesting question! Do you want fomular or vba?

Comment: Preferably VBA. It's part of a larger procedure but this portion of it just has me stumped.

Comment: I have a fomular solution... Let me think a vba solution...

Comment: I do not know whether my understanding is correct? If your have large rows the `find` function is faster.

Comment: How do you want to handle the blanks?  Should they be removed?  Or should "blank" be treated as a value to be deleted if there is a blank in the other column?

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. Re-reading it now I see that my question and example were a little ambiguous. The pairs of matching data could be from any row (A3 = 3.1, B3 = 0.5 and A17 = 2.4, B17 = 3.1 would still be a "pair" for the 3.1 data points). @RonRosenfeld provided the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach using VBA's Collection object to determine if there is a match.  It should execute much more quickly than methods that manipulate the worksheet directly, but, if your database is extensive and the execution is still too slow, there are some ways of speeding this up also.

The Source (original Data) and Results are in different places on the same worksheet, but it should be obvious in the code how to change that (or even change it to overwrite the original data, should you want that.

Blanks are not included.  If you want to include, the modifications to the code would be trivial

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteDuplicateColumnPairs()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim colFirst As Collection, colSecond As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long

'Set Source and Results worksheets and result range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet3")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet3")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Range("D1")

'Get source data
With wsSrc
    LastRow = .Range("a1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B")).Find(what:="*", after:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, _
                searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    vSrc = .Range("a1", .Cells(LastRow, "B"))
End With

'Collect first column data
'skip header row
Set colFirst = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    If Len(vSrc(I, 1)) > 0 Then
    colFirst.Add Item:=vSrc(I, 1), Key:=CStr(vSrc(I, 1))
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 457
            colFirst.Add Item:=vSrc(I, 1)
            Err.Clear
        Case Is <> 0
            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source
            Stop  'for debugging.
    End Select
    End If
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'collect second column data
'if present in first column, then remove from both
'  but will then need to see if there is a duplicate in first column
'  and re-enter it with the key

Set colSecond = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    If Len(vSrc(I, 2)) > 0 Then
    V = colFirst(CStr(vSrc(I, 2)))
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 5
            colSecond.Add vSrc(I, 2)
            Err.Clear
        Case 0
            colFirst.Remove (CStr(vSrc(I, 2)))
            'is there another dup in colFirst?
            For J = 1 To colFirst.Count
                If colFirst(J) = vSrc(I, 2) Then
                    colFirst.Remove J
                    colFirst.Add vSrc(I, 2), CStr(vSrc(I, 2))
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next J
        Case Else
            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source
            Stop
    End Select
    End If
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Construct Results Array
ReDim vRes(0 To IIf(colFirst.Count > colSecond.Count, colFirst.Count, colSecond.Count), 1 To 2)

'Populate headers
vRes(0, 1) = vSrc(1, 1)
vRes(0, 2) = vSrc(1, 2)

'Populate the data
For I = 1 To colFirst.Count
    vRes(I, 1) = colFirst(I)
Next I

For I = 1 To colSecond.Count
    vRes(I, 2) = colSecond(I)
Next I

'Write data to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

---

Here is an example of what this produces:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This did exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following code is of any help.

Answer:
Suppose Column A  and Column B have some numbers (say, 10), and there can be many duplicates (pairs).
The following routine will remove duplicate numbers:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 1 To 10
For j = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 2) Then
        Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
        Cells(j, 2).ClearContents
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Next

''''''''The next lines remove blank cells from columns A and B
Do
For i = 1 To 10
If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    Cells(i, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next
Loop While Cells(1, 1) = ""

Do
For i = 1 To 10
If Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
    Cells(i, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next
Loop While Cells(1, 2) = ""
End Sub
```

You can  combine two loops and modify the code to suit your needs.

Comment: Go the other way when deleting, For i = 10 to 1 step -1 otherwise it will only remove 1 blank when 2 exist. This can be avoided by building a range in the loop then deleting once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this code is modification of Vasant Kumbhojkar's code.

I posted it as new because I don't want to edit his answer.

So, every beginner can see code different and effective usage of looping.

You can try as follow:

```
Dim row, aRow, bRow, total As Integer

'Clear duplicate cell
For aRow = 1 To 10 Step 1

    For bRow = 1 To 10 Step 1

        If Cells(aRow, 1) = Cells(bRow, 2) Then

            Cells(aRow, 1).ClearContents

            Cells(bRow, 2).ClearContents

            Exit For

        End If

    Next bRow

Next aRow

'Clear blank cell from column A
row = 1
total = 10

Do While row <= total

    If Cells(row, 1) = "" Then
        Cells(row, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        total = total - 1
    Else
        row = row + 1
    End If

Loop

'Clear blank cell from column B
row = 1
total = 10

Do While row <= total

    If Cells(row, 2) = "" Then
        Cells(row, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        total = total - 1
    Else
        row = row + 1
    End If

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is this:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
  0.1       3.2     delete
  0.5       0.1     
  3.2       0.1     delete
  1.4               
  100       200     delete
  200       100     delete
  300       400     delete
  300       500     
  400       300     delete
```

[image]

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub FindPairs()

Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim search As Range, result As Range, pair_right As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

lastRow = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set search = Cells(i, 1)
    Set pair_right = Range(search.Address).Offset(0, 1)

    If search <> "" Then
        With Worksheets("sheet2").Columns(2)
            Set result = .find(what:=search, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not result Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = result.Address
                If Range(firstAddress).Offset(0, -1) = pair_right Then
                    pair_right.Offset(0, 1) = "delete" 'mark row for delete
                Else
                    Do
                        Set result = .FindNext(result)
                        If Not result Is Nothing _
                        And result.Address <> firstAddress _
                        And Range(result.Address).Offset(0, -1) = pair_right _
                        Then
                            pair_right.Offset(0, 1) = "delete"
                        End If
                    Loop While Not result Is Nothing And result.Address <> firstAddress
                 End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next i

' how to delete marked rows?
' if your have large row then clear contents will better
' after clear contents then sort

End Sub
```

If you really want use vba delete try this:

```
Sub DeleteRow()
For i = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 3) = "delete" Then
        Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

**Another method - Fomular**

```
  Column1   Column2 Connect2-1  Match
    0.1      3.2    3.2|0.1      4
    0.5      0.1    0.1|0.5      #N/A
    3.2      0.1    0.1|3.2      2
    1.4             |1.4         #N/A
    100      200    200|100      7
    200      100    100|200      6
    300      400    400|300      10
    300      500    500|300      #N/A
    400      300    300|400      8
```

[image]

1. Concatenate column A and B.

   `C2=CONCATENATE(B2,"|",A2)`
2. Match same data.

   `D2=MATCH(A2&"|"&B2,C:C,0)`
3. Filter Column D with `#N/A`

Comment: I think, you are wrong. He just want to delete cells which are matched.